# Azure Authentication error

Tags: android, azure, authentication

I am trying to implement azure authentication in my app. While loggin i am getting the following error on callback.

I/BasicWebViewClient: 2016-09-09 11:05:36-861ccdea-817d-46ac-8a5e-167baaa2d327-Sending intent to cancel authentication activity ver:1.1.1

09-09 16:35:37.586 2318-2318/com.example.demoazure E/exc: User cancelled the flow RequestId:241649731 CorrelationId: da49e002-edaa-4e9d-8571-09eb2a714b79

Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            mContext = new AuthenticationContext(MainActivity.this, authority, true);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mContext.acquireToken(MainActivity.this, resource, clientId, redirect, user_loginhint, PromptBehavior.Auto, "",
                callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (mContext != null) {
            mContext.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult> callback = new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception exc) {
            if (exc instanceof AuthenticationException) {

                Log.e("exc",exc.getMessage());
                //textViewStatus.setText("Cancelled");
                Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled");
            } else {
                //textViewStatus.setText("Authentication error:" + exc.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG, "Authentication error:" + exc.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
            mResult = result;

            Log.e("success","success");

            if (result == null || result.getAccessToken() == null
                    || result.getAccessToken().isEmpty()) {
                //textViewStatus.setText("Token is empty");
                Log.d(TAG, "Token is empty");
            } else {
                // request is successful
                Log.d(TAG, "Status:" + result.getStatus() + " Expired:"
                        + result.getExpiresOn().toString());
               // textViewStatus.setText(PASSED);
            }
        }
    };
```

Any help will be appreciated.

LogCat:

```
09-09 17:10:18.853 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-09 17:10:18.928 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.demoazure-1/lib/arm
09-09 17:10:20.781 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.demoazure-1/lib/arm
09-09 17:10:21.564 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/PRNGFixes: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-null-No need to apply the fix ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.565 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/PRNGFixes: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-null-No need to apply the fix ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.632 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/DefaultTokenCacheStore: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-null-Started to initialize storage helper ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.633 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/DefaultTokenCacheStore: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-null-Finished to initialize storage helper ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.645 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Sending async task from thread:23883 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.650 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Running task in thread:24066 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.655 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Start validating authority ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.660 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Finish validating authority:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common result:true ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.661 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Authority is validated: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.662 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Token request started ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.670 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure W/BrokerProxy: DEVELOPER_BROKER_PERMISSIONS_MISSING:2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Broker related permissions are missing for GET_ACCOUNTS, MANAGE_ACCOUNTS, USE_CREDENTIALS ver:1.1.1 
09-09 17:10:21.672 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Checking refresh tokens ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.673 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Looking for regular refresh token ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.674 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Looking for Multi Resource Refresh token ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.675 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Refresh token is not available ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.677 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Starting Authentication Activity with callback:128920197 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.679 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Put waiting request: 128920197 CorrelationId: a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:21.698 23883-24067/com.example.demoazure D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-09 17:10:21.743 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 53.0.2785.97 (code 278509700)
09-09 17:10:21.963 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
09-09 17:10:21.963 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
09-09 17:10:21.967 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
09-09 17:10:21.967 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
09-09 17:10:22.029 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 20 ms (timestamps 9402-9422)
09-09 17:10:22.032 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "53.0.2785.97", actual native library version number "53.0.2785.97"
09-09 17:10:22.112 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {ce28790}
09-09 17:10:22.113 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "53.0.2785.97", actual native library version number "53.0.2785.97"
09-09 17:10:22.139 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(151)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
09-09 17:10:22.179 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
09-09 17:10:22.392 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/09/15, 6cbbf7d, I3193f6e94a
09-09 17:10:22.590 23883-24115/com.example.demoazure W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
09-09 17:10:22.756 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524290
09-09 17:10:22.815 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
09-09 17:10:22.822 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Packagename:com.example.demoazure Broker packagename:com.microsoft.windowsintune.companyportal Calling packagename:com.example.demoazure ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.850 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-OnCreate redirectUrl:http://a14idt ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.854 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-User agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; XT1068 Build/MPB24.65-34; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.97 Mobile Safari/537.36 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.865 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Init broadcastReceiver with requestId:128920197 Request authority:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common resource:http://win8webapp.azurewebsites.net/  clientid:da2310c5-97b4-44f8-8b03-29fd0424895a ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.869 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; XT1068 Build/MPB24.65-34; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.97 Mobile Safari/537.36 PKeyAuth/1.0 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.870 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Packagename:com.example.demoazure Broker packagename:com.microsoft.windowsintune.companyportal Calling packagename:com.example.demoazure ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.872 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-OnCreate startUrl:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=da2310c5-97b4-44f8-8b03-29fd0424895a&resource=http%3A%2F%2Fwin8webapp.azurewebsites.net%2F+&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fa14idt&state=YT1odHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vY29tbW9uJnI9aHR0cDovL3dpbjh3
                                                                               ZWJhcHAuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIA
                                                                               &x-client-SKU=Android&x-client-Ver=1.1.1&x-client-OS=23&x-client-DM=XT1068&client-request-id=a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930 calling package:null ver:1.1.1  device:6.0 motorolaXT1068
09-09 17:10:22.881 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-onResume ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.915 23883-23889/com.example.demoazure I/art: Debugger is no longer active
09-09 17:10:22.984 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-AuthenticationActivity onPause unregister receiver ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.985 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:22-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Spinner at onPause will dismiss ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:22.986 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/Choreographer: Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-09 17:10:23.049 23883-24067/com.example.demoazure I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-09 17:10:23.203 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524290
09-09 17:10:23.338 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
09-09 17:10:23.798 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23883
09-09 17:10:23.809 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/BasicWebViewClient: 2016-09-09 11:40:23-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Page finished:about:blank ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:23.824 23883-24183/com.example.demoazure E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-09 17:10:23.843 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:23-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-displaySpinner:true showing:false ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:24.164 23883-24183/com.example.demoazure W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
09-09 17:10:24.185 23883-24183/com.example.demoazure W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
09-09 17:10:24.226 23883-24183/com.example.demoazure I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
09-09 17:10:24.324 23883-23894/com.example.demoazure I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17951(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 6(120KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 8MB/14MB, paused 16.551ms total 214.577ms
09-09 17:10:24.339 23883-23894/com.example.demoazure W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.470ms
09-09 17:10:26.452 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:26-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-AuthenticationActivity onRestart ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:26.478 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:26-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-onResume ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:26.480 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:26-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Webview onResume will register receiver:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=da2310c5-97b4-44f8-8b03-29fd0424895a&resource=http%3A%2F%2Fwin8webapp.azurewebsites.net%2F+&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fa14idt&state=YT1odHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vY29tbW9uJnI9aHR0cDovL3dpbjh3
                                                                               ZWJhcHAuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIA
                                                                               &x-client-SKU=Android&x-client-Ver=1.1.1&x-client-OS=23&x-client-DM=XT1068&client-request-id=a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:26.481 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:26-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Webview onResume register broadcast receiver for requestId128920197 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:29.439 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23883
09-09 17:10:31.185 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/BasicWebViewClient: 2016-09-09 11:40:31-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Page finished:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=da2310c5-97b4-44f8-8b03-29fd0424895a&resource=http%3A%2F%2Fwin8webapp.azurewebsites.net%2F+&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fa14idt&state=YT1odHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vY29tbW9uJnI9aHR0cDovL3dpbjh3ZWJhcHAuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIA&x-client-SKU=Android&x-client-Ver=1.1.1&x-client-OS=23&x-client-DM=XT1068&client-request-id=a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:31.186 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:31-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-displaySpinner:false showing:false ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:56.604 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:56-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-AuthenticationActivity onPause unregister receiver ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:56.605 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:56-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Spinner at onPause will dismiss ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:57.178 23883-23889/com.example.demoazure I/art: Debugger is no longer active
09-09 17:10:57.304 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:57-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-AuthenticationActivity onRestart ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:57.434 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:57-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-onResume ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:57.438 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:57-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Webview onResume will register receiver:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=da2310c5-97b4-44f8-8b03-29fd0424895a&resource=http%3A%2F%2Fwin8webapp.azurewebsites.net%2F+&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fa14idt&state=YT1odHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vY29tbW9uJnI9aHR0cDovL3dpbjh3
                                                                               ZWJhcHAuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIA
                                                                               &x-client-SKU=Android&x-client-Ver=1.1.1&x-client-OS=23&x-client-DM=XT1068&client-request-id=a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:10:57.439 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:40:57-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Webview onResume register broadcast receiver for requestId128920197 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:11:27.821 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:41:27-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-AuthenticationActivity onPause unregister receiver ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:11:27.823 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:41:27-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Spinner at onPause will dismiss ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:11:40.729 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:41:40-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-AuthenticationActivity onRestart ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:11:40.732 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:41:40-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-onResume ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:11:40.733 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:41:40-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Webview onResume will register receiver:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=da2310c5-97b4-44f8-8b03-29fd0424895a&resource=http%3A%2F%2Fwin8webapp.azurewebsites.net%2F+&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fa14idt&state=YT1odHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vY29tbW9uJnI9aHR0cDovL3dpbjh3
                                                                               ZWJhcHAuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIA
                                                                               &x-client-SKU=Android&x-client-Ver=1.1.1&x-client-OS=23&x-client-DM=XT1068&client-request-id=a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:11:40.734 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:41:40-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Webview onResume register broadcast receiver for requestId128920197 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:11:45.666 23883-24067/com.example.demoazure E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xba1ced10
09-09 17:11:45.682 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
09-09 17:11:53.291 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-09 17:11:53.291 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-09 17:12:33.255 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-09 17:12:33.271 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-09 17:12:34.728 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-09 17:12:34.729 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-09 17:12:37.908 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-09 17:12:37.910 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-09 17:12:38.903 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-09 17:12:38.908 23883-24150/com.example.demoazure D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524294
09-09 17:12:42.883 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:42:42-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-displaySpinner:true showing:false ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:12:45.938 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23883
09-09 17:12:46.472 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/BasicWebViewClient: 2016-09-09 11:42:46-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Page finished:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:12:46.473 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:42:46-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-displaySpinner:false showing:true ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:12:46.482 23883-24067/com.example.demoazure E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xba68b340
09-09 17:12:53.558 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.558 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.559 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.559 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.559 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.562 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.563 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.563 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.564 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:12:53.564 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
09-09 17:13:29.819 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:29-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-displaySpinner:true showing:false ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.273 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-displaySpinner:true showing:true ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.282 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/BasicWebViewClient: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Navigation is detected ver:1.1.1
                                                                           Timestamp: 2016-09-09 11:43:32Z ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.306 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure I/BasicWebViewClient: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Sending intent to cancel authentication activity ver:1.1.1 
09-09 17:13:33.309 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Sending intent to cancel authentication activity ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.313 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Return To Caller:2001 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.314 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-displaySpinner:false showing:true ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.319 23883-24067/com.example.demoazure E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xba3e41a8
09-09 17:13:33.325 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Return To Caller REQUEST_ID:128920197 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.329 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Packagename:com.example.demoazure Broker packagename:com.microsoft.windowsintune.companyportal Calling packagename:com.example.demoazure ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.346 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-AuthenticationActivity onPause unregister receiver ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.349 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationActivity: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Spinner at onPause will dismiss ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.359 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23883
09-09 17:13:33.382 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Get waiting request: 128920197 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.383 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-onActivityResult RequestId:128920197 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.385 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-User cancelled the flow RequestId:128920197 CorrelationId: a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.400 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Sending error to callback CorrelationId: a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930 ver:1.1.1
09-09 17:13:33.400 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure E/exc: User cancelled the flow RequestId:128920197 CorrelationId: a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930
09-09 17:13:33.401 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure D/tag: Cancelled
09-09 17:13:33.412 23883-23883/com.example.demoazure V/BasicWebViewClient: 2016-09-09 11:43:33-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Page finished:http://a14idt/?error=invalid_resource&error_description=AADSTS50001%3a+The+application+named+http%3a%2f%2fwin8webapp.azurewebsites.net%2f+was+not+found+in+the+tenant+named+thea14.com.++This+can+happen+if+the+application+has+not+been+installed+by+the+administrator+of+the+tenant+or+consented+to+by+any+user+in+the+tenant.++You+might+have+sent+your+authentication+request+to+the+wrong+tenant.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+49c97d40-e05e-491f-b601-f349d4fed8e8%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a8fbdb87-7fbb-4db8-b14c-05b5da575930%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2016-09-09+11%3a43%3a32Z&state=YT1odHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vY29tbW9uJnI9aHR0cDovL3dpbjh3ZWJhcHAuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIA ver:1.1.1
```

Comment: can you post full logcat.

Comment: please check logcat @VishalThakkar

Comment: hey  i have checked you log cat see my answer and check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed DEVELOPER_BROKER_PERMISSIONS.

You could try integrating your Android Application with Azure Active Directory by referring the following article:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-adal-sso-authentication/

For further information, you could also refer:

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/28/azure-mobile-services-net-updates/

Comment: could u tell me what is resource id in this??

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/resource-group-template-functions.md#resourceid

Comment: developer broker permissions were not for azure..i solved the problem :)

Comment: i have seen in your logcat  this W/BrokerProxy: DEVELOPER_BROKER_PERMISSIONS_MISSING:2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Broker related permissions are missing for GET_ACCOUNTS, MANAGE_ACCOUNTS, USE_CREDENTIALS ver:1.1.1 
09-09 17:10:21.672 23883-24066/com.example.demoazure V/AuthenticationContext: 2016-09-09 11:40:21-7be16668-be3d-4554-8d94-f9968015fd22-Checking refresh tokens ver:1.1.1

Comment: so i guess may be its caused of your problem.

Comment: no the problem was with the permisions and the resource url

Comment: @NehaTyagi ohk. mam.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try use AD from android and found similar problems to me;

see my coment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43203464/1005462
should be helpfull as start point of proper configs, etc;